# Is it possible to add route at runtime in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am creating a project in MVC3 along with C# for a local college. The requirement was to show teacher profile when something like www.mysite.com/teachercode  is entered in browser.

I have made a method ShowTeacher in my Teacher controller class. My Plan is to lookup database on application start and for every teacher register the same route as shown below, which will handle the request further, is this approach correct?

```
foreach(Teacher tch in TeacherCollection)
routes.MapRoute(
            "Teacher route" + tch.Id,
            tch.TeacherCode,
            new { controller = "Teacher", action = "ShowTeacher" }
        );
```

Secondly if a new teacher is added in database, is it possible to add the route as soon as teacher is saved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to add a route at runtime, instead you can set up a route that will catch URLs of the form *www.mysite.com/teachercode*, so long as none of your *teachercodes* have the same name as any of your controllers.

In `RegisterRoutes`, add another route (which needs to be the *first* one), which will route queries to the `ShowTeacher` action method of your `TeacherController`, along with a [route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Teacher route", // route name
    "{teacherCode}", // url
    new { controller = "Teacher", action = "ShowTeacher" }, // defaults
    new { teacherCode = @"[A-Za-z]{1,10}" } // constraints
    );
```

The constraint in this example - `@"[A-Za-z]{1,10}"` - is speciying that the *teachercode* will contain only upper or lowercase letters, and is between 1 and 10 characters long. You can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: What will happen, if user enters www.mysite.com in the browser, in that case user will be taken to the Teacher route, isn't it so? But I want user to go at home controller in this case.
Also I want to know this thing for my knowledge as well.

Comment: @ImranBalouch If the user enters _www.mysite.com_ then this route won't get used, because it uses a route constraint that requires at least one character in the path of the URL.

Comment: wow, awesome man! yesterday this thing took a good enough time of mine, I was using same approach but with out constraints, lolz 
Thanks for the answer my friend, I got answer to my question, but for my knowledge can you please tell me if it is possible to add route at runtime?

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness here, you can add/edit routes using the RouteMagic NuGet package, written by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx